# Windows 7 IIS 7.0 - setting an application to run under localhost

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7, vs-web-application-project

If i create a web application inside Visual Studio called MyWebApp, how can I make sure it can be accessed at the following address:

http://localhost/MyWebApp

NO PORTS required

thanks

VS 2010
IIS 7.0
Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http is by default run on port tcp/80.

writing http://address.com/ is the same as http://address.com:80/

If IIS is configured to use the default port of 80, then you do not need to specify anything.

Comment: Can you have several applications running under the same port? I am asking because in Windows XP set up, I didn't change any ports, everything ran under the same port, when added to IIS and configured as app.

Comment: Sure you can. In our environment, we have a farm of web servers, hosting many different applications. Some share the same application pool, while others have one application pool per application. This depends on requirements like memory usage, recycling times and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out why the web app wasn't running on localhost/MyWebApp. In VS 2010, there is a setting to NOT use the VS development server and yes, you are correct. If this setting is off, then the app runs on port 80 or localhost/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add that application to IIS (with the name "MyWebApp"), make sure the root folder for the application is pointing to the root folder of the project on your computer.